# Canvas only shows a black screen when trying to drawImage /w React-webcam

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas, webcam

I got stuck while coding a webcam app with reactjs

The reason I am using react-webcam only for the input and a separate canvas element as output is because I need to draw something on top of the output.

But the only thing I see is a black screen.. Nothing more, and I don't get it why. My console.log gives me some "positive" output, means that it logs video.readyState=4 and it shows me a video element. But it only renders a black screen.. Hope someone can give me a hint.

I got inspired by this article: https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258
and: [Draw rectangle over HTML 5 tag video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702127/draw-rectangle-over-html-5-tag-video)

Here is the relevant file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";

const VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS = {
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  facingMode: "user",
  deviceId: "",
  frameRate: { max: 1, ideal: 1 },
};

const Stream = () => {
  const webcamRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<Webcam>;
  const canvasRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  const [mediaStreamReady, setMediaStreamReady] = useState(false);

  const draw = (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, video: HTMLVideoElement) => {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS.width, VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS.height);
    ctx.translate(VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS.width, 0);
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
    ctx.clip();
    console.log(video);
    ctx.drawImage(
      video,
      0,
      0,
      VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS.width,
      VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS.height,
    );
  };

  const onUserMediaError = () => {
    console.log("ERROR in Camera!");
  };

  const onUserMedia = () => {
    console.log("onUserMedia: Camera loaded!");
    setMediaStreamReady(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS.width;
    canvas.height = VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS.height;
    if (!ctx) return;
    if (!mediaStreamReady) return;
    const render = () => {
      const video = webcamRef.current.video;
      if (!video) return;
      console.log("render..");
      draw(ctx, video);
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };
    render();
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Webcam
        audio={false}
        ref={webcamRef}
        videoConstraints={VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS}
        onUserMediaError={onUserMediaError}
        onUserMedia={onUserMedia}
        style={{ opacity: 1 }}
        width={"200px"} // only to get safe that I receive a stream
        height={"100px"} // only to get safe that I receive a stream
      />
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Stream;
```